# IBM Rational DOORS: Use case extensions?

Tags: requirements, ibm-doors, ibm-rational

I'm investigating how to implement use case extension points in DOORS requirements. To this end, I wanted to know if a DOORS object in one module can reference or link to a DOORS object in a second module. If so, I figure I can have my use cases with the extension points in a high level module, then I can have extension variations in a separate DOORS module, with each one referencing the DOORS object with the extension point it is instantiating. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If someone answers your questions, you can comment and ask them to clarify, or accept.  I notice you haven't accepted any of your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only link from one object to another. The objects can be in different modules.

Sometimes we wanted to link to a whole module. We created a first "title" object in the module we wanted to link to, and we linked to that.

DOORS is really dismal. Glad we ditched it.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely link an object in one DOORS module to another.  That's one of the main features of DOORS so that you can track your requirements between modules.  For example systems level statement of work type documents may be your initial source of requirements, kept in a high level module, and then that can be linked bidirectionally with finer grained software requirements, and then can be further linked to software components or lines of code or test cases.

If you right click a requirement you should see the "Link" option I believe it's called.  I think you need to have both modules open, or it at least makes it easier.